# Why can't Google Chrome find my app.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I'm starting to learn Nodejs with a simple app. Google Chrome can't seem to find my app.js file in my /assets/js.app

[image: Here is the console errors]

And then as you can see, I believe I have the paths set ups correctly
[image]

Instead of {{ vm.message }} it should say Hello World.

Chrome keeps telling me it can't find the app.js file in the index.ejs template file, which looks like this

```
    <html ng-app="TestApp">
<title>The MEAN Stack</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    {{ vm.message }}
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this for source in index.ejs <script src="/assets/assets/js/app.js"></script>

Comment: you set `/assets` to your `/public` directory not your `/public/assets` directory, as is your url to the script would probably need to be `/assets/assets/js/app.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), the optional route prefix is not actually part of the file path, but rather it is appended to the url. You can use `/assets/assets/js/app.js`, but it may be better to just remove the prefix: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))`.

I would also say that `assets` should be reserved for things like images and that `js` and perhaps even `css` belong in their own higher level directories, but this is debatable.

Serving static content from `express` is fine for development or toy apps, but in a real production app you should look into a better static file server than node.js.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer and explanation... helps in my journey of learning.